# What does "fixed but random" mean exactly?

Tags: econometrics

I am studying econometrics and bumped into such thing as "fixed but random" variables. As far as I understood, these are the observations that will become constant values in the future, when they are observed. But until they are not, so while we are "theorising", they can be seen as random variables, e.g., they can be iid from each other, so have their own distribution.

That's how I understood the concept, at least. So, we know that they aren't fully random variables: we know that each of them is a separated number, but we don't know which number exactly, so it is yet random. A random observation, so to say. And it has a distribution. Or is it the underlying random variable that has the distribution?

Sorry, I think I got confused. Especially because different textbooks and professors explain it differently and use different notations. I would be more than grateful if you provide any explanation or at least links to proper literature.

Sorry if it's not the proper place, but I don't know where else to ask. When I try to google "fixed but random", it results in distinguishing between fixed and random effects of panel data.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT -------------

First of all, thank you so much for taking time to comment and answer me!

1. About the term itself:

I have heard the "fixed but random" term from only one of my professors, and have never seen it anywhere else. I just thought that it is how these things are called among those who are deeply into econometrics or something. It is definitely not from Bayes statistic, as I haven't yet got that far.

2. About what I actually do not understand

I will try to describe a more precise situation for which I thought the term "fixed but random" is used (now, thanks to you, I understand that I was wrong).

I will now be "quoting" the lectures of one of my professors. They assume the case of linear regression model and write it like this:

$Y = b_1X_1 + ... + b_nX_n + e$

Then they say that in terms of the **sample** this model corresponds to:

$y_i = x_i^T b +e_i$

i = 1, ..., n,

where **x_i** and **b** are vectors.

And then they state the assumptions for the model like this:

the process/sequence

$(y_i , x_i^T)$

i ∊ ℕ

is iid.

And this is where I get confused. As far as I understand, the **random variables** are those Y and X_1, ..., X_n of the initial model. And y_i and x_i are a single (i-th) **observation** of Y and a vector of (i-th) **observations** of X respectively. So, they are fixed. But here comes a question: how can observations be iid from each other if they are fixed, so they don't have their own distribution, they are just constants.

That's why I thought that such observations are called "fixed but random", because we consider them to be not yet observations (we look at the distribution from which they occur), but not random variables, too, since we know that they are supposed to be fixed numbers. Probably I am somewhere wrong here. I would be very grateful if you could provide the explanation. I hope I described the situation more clearly now.

Thank you!

EDIT 2: I tried to ask it as a separate question but it got closed with some links to questions like "what is a random variable?" I understand how rv's differ from non-random values. I wanted explanation for this specific setting and formulation. So I will leave the edition here. Maybe someone will answer.

Comment: This does not strike me as common terminology. Where exactly did you encounter it? If there is a textbook, would you be able to point to where in the textbook this terminology arises?

Comment: Apropos of nothing, I can't begin to guess at the meaning. Could it perhaps be the idea of a "random variable" which takes a single value with probability 1?

Comment: The phrasing on fixed/random effects is a complete mess out there and nobody understands it, because everyone uses different definitions.

Comment: If you're looking through a textbook and want an explanation of what the textbook's saying, I suggest finding the exact words the textbook uses and adding them here so we can better understand what you're looking for.

Comment: I have edited the initial post providing an example which I can't understand. Maybe this will help. Thank you.

Comment: @Anatole12: Thanks for your attempt to clarify your question.  In this instance your edit appears to raise an entirely new question (about regression modelling) than your original post.  Rather than including this as an edit to the present question, I suggest removing it and posting it as a new question on this forum (with a title that reflects the content).

Comment: @Ben , I understood you. Will do. Thank you.

Comment: *"But here comes a question: how can observations be iid from each other if they are fixed, so they don't have their own distribution, they are just constants."* What do you mean by 'if they are fixed'? You do not explain this further in the question. *" So, they are fixed."* what do you mean by 'they are fixed'? Is this like calling a specific realization of some coin flips or dice rolls a fixed vector?

Comment: By saying "they are fixed" I mean that they are constants already. As if we have conducted an experiment and taken out a concrete sample of numbers. While theorising, we do not precise these numbers, but we consider them to be "fixed", so, to be constants.

Comment: anatole12, so this is like considering a random coin toss being intrinsically deterministic and therefore fixed? Or are you referring to a different principle?

Comment: *"we have conducted an experiment and taken out a concrete sample of numbers."* What do you mean by 'taken out a concrete sample of numbers'.

Comment: The fact that you're getting multiple radically different answers, all of which you reject, tells us this question needs substantial cleaning up to make it understandable.  Although I hate to close both versions of your question, this is necessary to prevent others from contributing yet more confusion to this thread.  I wonder whether you are trying to ask about *conditioning* on values of random variables or, perhaps generally, how probability theory accounts for the processes of modeling quantities as random variables, observing them, and consequently updating information.

Answer (score 2):

*"fixed but random"* is **not a common term** with a clear consensus about it's meaning.

The occurance of the term in the English literature is not common and half the time it is part of the phrase "not fixed but random"

[image: occurance]

Note that 'fixed but random' is not a contradiction when 'fixed' and 'random' relate to different things. But which relations, that depends on the context.

- Searching for the term on Google scholar I see several cases where 'fixed' refers to the situation where an object of study is fixed. And the 'random' part refers to the situation where this fixed state has been generated random.

  For instance [here](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.71.061105)

  > We are in a typical situation of the quenched disorder [3,4] when the motion of particles in a fixed but random environment is considered. That is why inevitably we are
  > faced with an averaging procedure, which helps us to pass to the macroscopic transport equation. $$$$ We have a fixed realization $b(x)=b(x_n)=b_n$ of a random
  > process (well depths)  with the probability distribution $P(b)$
- A situation of 'fixed but random' could also be the situation with Bayesian statistics where we use a prior distributions to express the probability distribution of some value which in reality may be a fixed value.
- Another situation of 'fixed but random' could be in description of random number generators. These can come up with a fixed sequence every time, but the numbers have a random character.

So this combination 'fixed but random' may occur and the meaning depends on the context. What it means for your econometrics case is not clear (since it is broad). It requires the specific context in order to say anything more about it.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer so broadly. I guess that this term really has nothing to do with what I am trying to grasp. I have edited the initial post providing an example which I can't understand. Maybe this will help. Thank you.

Comment: While an ngram may be helpful, it is possible to get the sentence fragment "fixed but random" in a sentence like this: "The location of the container is fixed but random forces impact the contents of the container."  In this example there is not object that is being asserted as both fixed and random.

Comment: @Ben indeed the expression "fixed but random" can be part of a sentence with a wider context. This is why I used to also search for "not fixed but random". That single phrase alone already shows that roughly half the occurrences are due to being part of "not fixed but random".

Comment: We could try to search for your suggestion with "_VERB_ fixed but random" but nothing like it occurs. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fixed+but+random%2C_VERB_+fixed+but+random%2C+not+fixed+but+random&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfixed%20but%20random%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20fixed%20but%20random%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very hand-wavy but hopefully captures the intuition of "fixed but random."

We sometimes assume that the observations on the explanatory variables can be considered fixed. For example, if Framer Ron is studying fertilizer's effect on turnip yield, he fixes the value of the manure dummy to one when he applies the fertilizer to a plot and zero when he does not. Then all the randomness in crop yield comes from unobserved characteristics of the plot, like how close the rabbit warren is (assuming rabbits steal turnips).

The next level is fixed *in repeated samples*. That is, it is possible to redraw the sample with the same explanatory variable values. This is often weak­ened to read that the explanatory variables are random but independent of the error term. For example, if I sample people from all over Canada, there are ten provinces and three territories. If you imagine there is some unknown province/territory-level effect, if you sample enough people from each, you can get a good handle on those 13 effects using dummy variables. In this case, it often makes sense to think of each unit-level effect $\alpha_i$ as an unknown parameter (so random to the analyst), but fixed once you look at enough data since there are only so many provinces. This is most likely what "fixed but random" means. An extreme example of this is a census, where the sample is the population.

This is in contrast to a panel data set where you sample units from some population. A [consumer panel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Consumer_Panel) is one example, where you track a sample of households and their shopping over time. In that case, the household-level effect $u_i$ is not fixed since each time you sample a household you get a completely new $u_i$ draw. Here repeated sampling does not help you pin down the household effect, so it is in some sense more random and not fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer so broadly. I have read your examples but I think that it is not what I faced, so I probably misused the term. Thank you for helping me realize that. I have edited the initial post providing an example which I can't understand. Maybe this will help to clarify the situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as something being simultaneously "fixed but random" --- those are contradictory concepts and this appelation is not used in statistics or econometrics so far as I am aware.  (If you can provide a source for the occurrence of this appelation then I'm happy to look at it.)  In classical statistics we sometimes refer to parameters as "unknown constants" (i.e., fixed but *unknown*) but we wouldn't refer to something as "fixed but random".  We also often take quantities that are *fixed but unknown* (fixed in an aleatory sense) and treat these as random variables in an epistemological sense because they are unknown.

While there is no such thing as something being fixed and random at the same time, in probability and statistics we often consider random variables that are considered to be random prior to occurrence or observation, but fixed after they become manifest or observed.  This means that problems frequently feature instances of a random variable (sometimes denoted in upper-case) and corresponding instances of its outcome (denoted in lower-case).  When you learn probability and statistics you frequently have to get used to seeing these upper and lower-case instances of the same variable, with one representing the pre-observational random variable and the other representing the post-observational fixed value.

Since you have not given a source or context for the notion of "fixed but random" my suspicion is that it is just an error, or a clumsy attempt to describe something else.  Without further context it is difficult to guess what this might be intended to describe.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer so broadly. I guess that this term really has nothing to do with what I am trying to grasp. I have edited the initial post providing an example which I can't understand. Maybe this will help. Thank you.

Comment: Re "no such thing:" I believe the entire population of the community of geostatisticians would beg to differ.  Their problems focus on predicting properties of *fixed* phenomena, such as the distribution of gold within a mining area, based on *random models.*

Comment: @whuber: Even in that context, there is no thing that is "fixed but random".  There is an unknown quantity that is treated mathematically as a random variable.  If you were to say the gold quantity was "fixed but random" in that context you would be mixing an aleatory description for "fixed" and an epistemological/mathematical description for "random".

Comment: The entire basis of the analysis underlying kriging treats the *observed* data, which typically are not conceived of as "unknown," as realizations of (part of) a random process.  Moreover--this is where the geological context is so compelling--there obviously is no opportunity to replicate that process or any part of it.

Comment: Sure, but once it is observed its value becomes known and therefore fixed in analysis.  As usual, once a random variable is observed it is then treated as a fixed conditioning value.  If you have in mind a quantity that is simultaneously fixed and random, please tell me what it is explicitly, and why it is both fixed and random.  I have no idea why we are talking about replication.

Comment: I would say your response shows that something can be both 'fixed' and 'random', if the terms are referring to different contexts or levels. Something can be physically 'fixed' in the material world, while being 'random' in an epistemological sense. In Bayesian terms, randomness is not a property of this material world, but of the information about it, hence there is no contradiction. The average height of a population at a given time is for sure a real fixed quantity that exists, yet it will be modelled as a random quantity. The term is for sure hand-wavy, but not meaningless.

Comment: There is no such thing as "random" in an epistemological sense --- there is just known and unknown.  That is the epistemological distinction used in subjective Bayesian statistics, and the appelation "random" comes in only as a mathematical term describing the "random variable".  Observe also that you had to equivocate from "is random" to "can be modelled by a random variable" which again confirms that the only use of "random" refers to a naming convention for a mathematical object.  It appears that we have to butcher the plain meaning of words in order to consolidate the two terms.